# RefineryCMS: overriding Devise Omniauth Callbacks

Tags: devise, omniauth, refinerycms

I am working on an application that I am wanting to authenticate through a custom oauth provider I have setup on a different server.

I am trying to integrate this custom login using RefineryCMS. I have my routes setup, but for some reason it is still trying to follow the devise route built into RefineryCMS.

Routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
devise_scope :users do
 match '/users/auth/:provider', :to => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru'
end
```

Link for callback

```
<p><%= link_to "Sign in with Olympus", user_omniauth_callback_path(:olympus) %></p>
```

Olympus is the codename for the project for now.

Omniauth callback controller:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def olympus
    auth = env["omniauth.auth"]
    ap auth
  end

  def passthru
    render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", :status => 404, :layout => false
  end
end
```

The log via rails s once the link is clicked on:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/olympus/callback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-12 07:52:09 -0500
  Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as 
  SQL (0.7ms)  SHOW TABLES
  SQL (0.6ms)  SHOW TABLES
  Page Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `pages`.`id`, `pages`.`depth`, `pages`.`parent_id`, `pages`.`lft`, `pages`.`rgt`, `pages`.`link_url`, `pages`.`menu_match`, page_translations.title as page_title FROM `pages` INNER JOIN `page_translations` ON `page_translations`.`page_id` = `pages`.`id` WHERE `pages`.`draft` = 0 AND `pages`.`show_in_menu` = 1 AND `page_translations`.`locale` = 'en' ORDER BY lft ASC
  Slug Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `slugs`.* FROM `slugs` WHERE (`slugs`.`sluggable_id` IN (1,3) and `slugs`.`sluggable_type` = 'Page' AND (`slugs`.`locale` = 'en')) ORDER BY id DESC
  Slug Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `slugs`.* FROM `slugs` WHERE (`slugs`.sluggable_id = 3 AND `slugs`.sluggable_type = 'Page') ORDER BY id DESC
  SQL (1.3ms)  describe `roles_users`
  Role Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `roles`.* FROM `roles` WHERE `roles`.`title` = 'Refinery' LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.4ms)  describe `roles_users`
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT * FROM `users` INNER JOIN `roles_users` ON `users`.id = `roles_users`.user_id WHERE (`roles_users`.role_id = 1 )
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/login
```

So its still trying to go through the Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController through RefineryCMS... Does anyone know how to get around this or maybe even override this devise controller?

I also would like to say that I am completely new to working with oauth providers/clients. I have worked with Facebook and Twitter but doing them from scratch is something I am new at. As well as working with Devise/Omniauth. So excuse my ignorance. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed routing issue by reading this article: http://groups.google.com/group/refinery-cms/browse_thread/thread/37917e227b26f5ca

The issue I am having now, is that it appears to not be connecting to my oauth provider to do the authenticating :(